# Mystery Database backups in logs

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

Our Differential backups will succeed one night and then fail the next. We suspect it is either related to the following logs

Every day at 7:19 we get this sequence of events in the log for each database we have in SQL Server

I/O is frozen on database DATABASENAME No user action is required. However, if I/O is not resumed promptly, you could cancel the backup.

I/O was resumed on database DATABASENAME No user action is required.

Database backed up. Database: DATABASENAME, creation date(time): 2010/11/04(23:28:04), pages dumped: 841, first LSN: 35:483:37, last LSN: 35:499:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'{F8C10393-542B-4491-8135-BE0545F42EBE}22'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

OR

that related to our online backup software Mozy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please not the backups that are failing are scheduled in SQL Server Maintenance Plan and failing with the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've seen this before with Mozy when it runs on a scheduled basis, it resets the archive bit and then SQL Server can't recognize the last full backup and the differentials fail.  Assuming at this point if you use the Mozy agent it will work for you.

Comment: Tony's response below seems to bear merit although it states its an exchange bug, perhaps it spans across into their SQL backup product as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is known error for MozyPro. Their technical support is still working on it to fix this issue. As you can see from this below post:

http://community.mozy.com/t5/Mozy-for-Windows/Incremental-Not-working/td-p/10123

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this message when the Symantec tape backup product is used to backup SQL Server databases.